# Side menu turns white when I scroll dow

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to implement a side menu in my application it works fine for the most part, but the problem I have is that once I display de menu and try to scroll down the whole list turns white (background) and the text disappears.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/asYL9.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1gQk.png

Above I attach two pictures showing the behavior of the menu, when I slide my finger from the left to the right the side menu shows, but if I scroll down in the menu, it becomes an empty white list, here is my code:

```
public class ControlApp extends SlidingActivity{

ArrayList<String> datos ;
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;
Intent intent;
private String[] mMenuLista;
//  private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notificaciones);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    Parse.initialize(this, "BqCCNsbb14MPgeWz3rznxO4DamuXUbsgiTug8P8I", "9j7GSLWnV46fkPsNMwnMD2FormAiclKlGitfDq2b"); 
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(100);

//      mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();



    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, Notificaciones.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    mMenuLista =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lista_menu);
//      for(int i=0; i<=9;i++){
//          mAdapter.addItem(mMenuLista[i]);
//          if(i == 9){
//              mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(mMenuLista[i]);
//          }
//      }



    ListView primario = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    primario.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.drawer_list, mMenuLista));



    primario.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> pariente, View view, int posicion, long id) {

            selectItem(posicion);

        }
    });





}

public void selectItem(int posicion){
    switch (posicion) {
    case 0:
        intent = new Intent(ControlApp.this, Notificaciones.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 1:
        intent = new Intent(ControlApp.this, Calificaiones.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 2:
        intent = new Intent(ControlApp.this, Mensajes.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 3:
        intent = new Intent(ControlApp.this, Citas.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 4:
        intent = new Intent(ControlApp.this, Permisos.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 5:
        intent = new Intent(ControlApp.this, Eventos.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 6:
        intent = new Intent(ControlApp.this, Horarios.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 7:
        intent = new Intent(ControlApp.this, Circulares.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 8:
        intent = new Intent(ControlApp.this, ProgramaDeEstudios.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 9:
        intent = new Intent(ControlApp.this, Ajustes.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 10:

        ParseUser.logOut();
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null){
            // sesion cerrada correctamente
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sesión cerrada correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            Intent regis = new Intent (ControlApp.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(regis);
            finish();
        }else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se logro cerrar sesion, intentelo de nuevo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



}
```

I hope someone can help me find my mistakes so I can correct the error. thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are manually setting the background color of a `ListView` in your menu to black, while the main activity theme has a white background?

You need to set the `android:cacheColorHint` attribute on the `ListView` to match the list background color. The white is appearing due to rendering optimization by Android which uses that `cacheColorHint` value to quickly redraw the list while scrolling.

I read a good blog post detailing this issue once. I can't find it right now but will link to it if I do :)

Comment: No worries, your answer solved my problem, you might as well be an angel... who knows!!! THANK YOU!!